# Error 403 when using Basic Authentication with Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, proxy, basic-authentication

Hi Everyone,

I followed the steps in the below link to accomplish Basic Authentication with Tomcat and I was successfully able to achieve the result:

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-basic-authentication-with-tomcat.html?page=1

I went then afterward to accomplish the same on an existing project I'm working on but I'm unfortunately getting error 403 ( Access to the specified resource has been forbidden) when trying to access the servlet either from the browser or through a java program. Error 403 means the user was authenticated but not authorized.

I did an in depth research on that issue but still I'm stuck there, so appreciate your help here.

Here is the tomcat-user.xml:

```html
<role rolename="tomee-admin"/>
<role rolename="adapter-role"/>
<user password="tomee" roles="tomee-admin,manager-gui" username="tomee"/>
<user username="adapter" password="adapterpwd" role="adapter-role"/>
```

Her is my web.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <display-name>sbee-adapter</display-name>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>OZZ-Adapter</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
      </user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>  
  <security-constraint>
 <web-resource-collection>
  <web-resource-name>OZZ-Adapter</web-resource-name>
  <url-pattern>/API</url-pattern>
 </web-resource-collection>
 <auth-constraint>
  <role-name>adapter-role</role-name>
 </auth-constraint>
 </security-constraint>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <servlet-name>IDP</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.xxxx.ozz.adapter.ztee.IDP</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>IDP</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/IDP</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>API</display-name>
    <servlet-name>API</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.xxxx.ozz.adapter.ztee.API</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>API</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/API</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  </login-config>
</web-app>
```

My java code:

```
HttpURLConnection con1 = (HttpURLConnection) urlSBEE_API.openConnection();
                con1.setRequestMethod("POST");
                String basis_encode = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("adapter" + ":" + "adapterpwd").getBytes("UTF-8"));
                con1.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + basis_encode);
    responseCode = con1.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("Response code====== "+responseCode);
```

the responseCode value is being 403.

I made sure to include in the web.xml the

```
<auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
```

as I saw on the net many suggestions to do that.

On the other hand if in the java code I enter a wrong username and pwd then I get error 401 which is correct since it means user not authenticated.

I cleared browser cache and retired. still same issue.

Could the issue be related to Proxy setting???

My windows proxy settings are as follow:
Use Automatic Configuration script, Address: http://proxy:8083/

I tried the following code as well:

```
     Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,
                            new InetSocketAddress("Proxy"),
                                    Integer.parseInt("8083"));
        HttpURLConnection con1 = (HttpURLConnection) urlDistribution.openConnection(proxy);
    con1.setRequestMethod("POST");
    String basis_encode = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("adapter" + ":" + "adapterpwd").getBytes("UTF-8"));
    con1.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + basis_encode);
    responseCode = con1.getResponseCode();
   System.out.println("Response code====== "+responseCode);
```

I tried including the following before HttpURLConnection con1 :

```
System.setProperty("http.nonProxyHosts", "<MY_LOCAL_HOST>");
```

but still no luck.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SOLUTION:

I just replaced in tomcat-user.xml:
role="adapter-role"

WITH

**roles**="adapter-role"